# Adding a column to a three columns file with awk

Tags: awk, scripting

I would like to add a new column to an existing matrix in file.txt using awk.
I have the file

```
  -1.664405      -0.019498       0.487501
  -2.210156       0.326547       1.193717
  -2.260318      -0.104277      -0.256821
   2.189078      -2.103898       1.321050
   1.558565      -1.476110       0.967988
   1.764428      -2.955372       1.216211
   ...
   ...
```

and I would like to have something like this

```
O     -1.664405      -0.019498       0.487501
H     -2.210156       0.326547       1.193717
H     -2.260318      -0.104277      -0.256821
O      2.189078      -2.103898       1.321050
H      1.558565      -1.476110       0.967988
H      1.764428      -2.955372       1.216211
    ...
    ...
```

O and H have to vary systematically in this form 100's of times.

Somebody knows how to do it with awk?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to explain the difference between `O` and `H`, in other words which should be used where.

Comment: Yes, indeed, thanks by the comment. O's and H's have to vary sistematically as they are:

Comment: If "column.txt" is the original file, and "column-new.txt" is the file with the new column, i.e., containing O,H,H, etc., then the command "paste column-new.txt column.txt" would work too - assuming the number of rows of both files are equal. I realize you asked for awk but I'm just trying to provide alternative method.

Comment: Still not sure what "systematically" means here; at random for each line, with roughly 50% `O` and 50% `H`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me how much indentation you would like, so I'm assuming just one whitespace between the new first column and the following.

If it has to be `awk` you might do with:

```c
awk '(NR-1)%3{print "H", $0; next}{print "O", $0}'
```

Else `sed` can be used as well:

```bsh
sed '1~3{s/^/O /p;d};s/^/H /'
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
awk '{ print (FNR-1) % 3 ? "H" : "O", $0 }' file
```

This uses `awk` to prefix the current line with an `H` or an `O` depending on whether the current line's line number is a multiple of three or not.

If you want a tab character as a delimiter between the new column and the others, make sure that `OFS` has the value `\t`:

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print (FNR-1) % 3 ? "H" : "O", $0 }' file
```

---

Using GNU `sed` specifically and assuming that you want the new column separated from the others with a tab character:

```bsh
sed -e '1~3 s/^/O\t/' -e '1~3! s/^/H\t/' file
```

The first expression adds `O` followed by a tab character to every third line starting at line 1.  The second adds `H` and a tab character to all lines that are not every third line starting at line 1.

This requires GNU `sed` due to the following two non-standard features:

1. The address `n~m` means "every `m`:th line, starting at line `n`".
2. The character sequence `\t` is expanded to a literal tab character.

---

Using other tools:

```bsh
yes 'O H H' | tr ' ' '\n' | head -n "$( wc -l <file )" | paste - file
```

This produces a steady stream of `O`, `H`, `H` (repeating) on separate lines using `yes` and `tr`.  This stream is cut short with `head` to match the number of lines in our file (this is calculated using `wc -l`).  The `O`:s and `H`:s are then inserted to the left of the rest of the file's contents using `paste`, with a tab character as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like that:

```
awk 'BEGIN {chars="OHH"; next_char=1} {print substr(chars, next_char, 1), $0; next_char++} next_char==4 {next_char=1}' matrix
```