# Adding and changing columns in a file with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the file of about 300 hundreds lines

```
TITLE      cargas
REMARK   1 File created by GaussView 5.0.9
HETATM    1  O           0       0.957  -0.000  -0.000                       O
HETATM    2  H           0       0.000   0.000   0.000                       H
HETATM    3  H           0       1.197   0.927  -0.000                       H
HETATM    4  O           0      -1.664  -0.019   0.488                       O
HETATM    5  H           0      -2.210   0.327   1.194                       H
HETATM    6  H           0      -2.260  -0.104  -0.257                       H
HETATM    7  O           0       2.189  -2.104   1.321                       O
HETATM    8  H           0       1.559  -1.476   0.968                       H
HETATM    9  H           0       1.764  -2.955   1.216                       H
  ...
```

and I would like to have the following form of the previous file

```
TITLE      cargas
REMARK   1 File created by GaussView 5.0.9
HETATM    1  O   LIG     1       0.957  -0.000  -0.000                       O
HETATM    2  H   LIG     1       0.000   0.000   0.000                       H
HETATM    3  H   LIG     1       1.197   0.927  -0.000                       H
HETATM    4  O   HOH     2      -1.664  -0.019   0.488                       O
HETATM    5  H   HOH     2      -2.210   0.327   1.194                       H
HETATM    6  H   HOH     2      -2.260  -0.104  -0.257                       H
HETATM    7  O   HOH     3       2.189  -2.104   1.321                       O
HETATM    8  H   HOH     3       1.559  -1.476   0.968                       H
HETATM    9  H   HOH     3       1.764  -2.955   1.216                       H
  ...
```

The first three rows have to say LIG and all the others HOH.
The numeration of column 5 varies from 1 to 100 by three rows each number.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: for the follow up question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/644599/72456، didn't you learn the idea from the previously given answers?

Comment: Well it is hard to admit, I learned a bit but you are right. It was not enough to do this myself, I am sorry for being a bit slow ...

Comment: @patprovasi don't worry, we all have to start somewhere. It's just that we expect the people who ask questions to put in some effort first. Presumably, you must have tried to figure this out and you didn't just come here to ask for others to do your work for you, so just add some of your attempts to the question. That way, we know not to repeat the solutions you have already tried that didn't work, and we also see that you have tried _something_ and are not using us as a free script writing service.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes indeed I had tryed. But I realise that most people also say what they tryed to do and I didn't

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
    (NR-2)%3==1 { inc++ }
    NR>2        { $4=(inc==1)?"LIG":"HOH"; $5=inc }1' infile
```

Above `awk` command is consist of two conditions followed by the block of actions enclosed within brackets like `condition{ "actions" }` (the *awk* common syntax).

In *awk*, the dollar sign `$` is the operator that return the column/field content of its parameter (note that by default *awk* consider sequences of Tabs/Spaces as the field separator).

based on above explanation exceptionally `$0` represent the current line/record content and`$1` for first field, `$2` second field, `$3` third field and so on.

NR is the *"The total number of input records seen so far."* (from man awk) and so that represent the current line number awk has read for processing.

In this condition `(NR-2)%3==1` we increment the variable `inc++` for each 4<sup>th</sup> line starting from the 3<sup>rd</sup> line (`NR-2` skip the first two lines); like consider for example in `(NR-0)%3==1` we do checks each 4<sup>th</sup> line but start from 1<sup>st</sup> line, or in `(NR-1)%3==1` doing the same but start from the second line; generally with `(NR-#)%3==1` we checks it's every 4<sup>th</sup> line but skipping first `#` number of lines.

do test with `awk '(NR-2)%3==1' infile` to see which lines it does print.

in the second block, i.e: `NR>2{ $4=(inc==1)?"LIG":"HOH"; $5=inc }`; we updates the content of the fields #4 and #5 only for the lines that have line number >2 `NR>2` (skipping first two line).

this `$4=(inc==1)?"LIG":"HOH"` sets the field #4 value to "LIG" until var `inc` still has value=1 else it will take "HOH" value; `$5=inc` is also take the value of the `inc` value accordingly.

the `1` at the end is *awk* idiom and always true condition to printout the current line; see [What is the meaning of '1' at the end of an awk script](/q/63891/72456) for details.

---

At the end, to keep the intention between fields, do:

```
awk -F'( )' '
    (NR-2)%3==1 { inc++ }
    NR>2        { $9=(inc==1)?"LIG":"HOH"; $14=inc }1' infile
```

or pass the first awk script output to  `awk ... |column -t`.